# Card title text size - Materialize

Tags: html, css, materialize

Okay, I've implemented Materialize. Everything works fine and I have a card.

A basic card like this: http://materializecss.com/cards.html

How do I change the card title size ?

I've tried doing adding my class like this:

```
             <div class="row">
                    <div class="col s12 m12">
                      <div class="card light-blue darken-3">
                        <div class="card-content white-text">
                          <center> <span class="card-title myClassHey">Prijava</span> </center>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

And then in the css:

```
    .myClassHey{
    color:red;
    size: 55px;
}
```

The color WORKS, but the size DOES NOT WORK. I've tried making a div id="myClassHey" and then calling in the css #myClassHey{ bla }; but that did not work also.

I just want to make the card title bigger.

Comment: color:red;
font-size: 55px !important;

Comment: `size` isn't a valid css property. are you looking for `height` or `width`?

Comment: and the `center` tag is deprecated - you shouldn't be using that. Use the `center-align` class on the parent instead.

Comment: @techLove ,you were close ! I just needed to use font-size: 55px !important; Thank mate.

Comment: @MichaelCoker Thanks, fixed the center issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just needed to use:
`font-size: 55px !important;`